# modellingwith TensorFlow

Tags: deep-learning

```
Epoch 1/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-ccb89cf8f810> in <module>
     13 
     14 # 3. Fit the model
---> 15 model.fit(X, Y, epochs=5)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 889, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 228, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_10" (type Sequential).
```

Comment: If you are asking strangers online to devote some of their time to help you with your problem, at least please take the time to explain it instead of just pasting the backtrace of the exception you are getting...

Answer (score 1):

With the little information that we have, I can suggest that this error is caused by the dimension of your input, it may be incompatible.